# what is alternative solution for GLKView Class? [deprecated in iOS 12]

Tags: ios, objective-c, glkview, xcode10, ios12

Apple had been deprecated GLKView class in iOS 12. Anybody share the answer for alternative solution for existing project and new project

[image]

Comment: You should use Metal instead of OpenGL.

Comment: I agree with @the4kman, apple depreciated GLKView, so that everyone switch to metal. Use `MTKView`.

Comment: did you already implement an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

openGL support is deprecated (iOS 12) so the alternative is to use metal and MTKView